# I want to make a filter facility for my category page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want a filter facility using the querystring in URL, e.g. if passed 
`http://www.mywebsite.com/category-url?filter_by=subcategory-url,subcategory-url`
I will shows only category using filter by parameter.

I've tried this:

```
# Mage_Catalog_CategoryController: _initCatagory():

if(isset($_GET['filter_by']) && !empty($_GET['filter_by'])){ //check if filter is enable
    $str_category_filter = trim($_GET['filter_by']);
    Mage::register('filterval', $str_category_filter); Mage::log('1'); //log set by omkar
} else {
    Mage::register('filterval', 0); Mage::log('0'); //log set by omkar
}
```

But it cannot set value properly and I want to fetch this value in 
`app\design\frontend\shopper\default\template\catalog\navigation\subcategory.phtml` page.

Comment: If getting the query string is what you want, then you can use `$_GET['filter_by']` directly from **subcategory.phtml** or better you can use Magento's `$this->getRequest()->getParam('filter_by');`.

Comment: subcategory.phtml is not user facing file it include via cms block so how to access any data from controller to this kinds of files

Comment: `$_GET` array is accessible through all files that are loaded, even those included via cms block. Now, if setting a registry is what you want, your implementation is right. What exactly is the problem? `Mage::registry('filterval')` is empty?